# Medoo - Updating table row matching field

Tags: php

I am using Medoo but know very little php, the update below works fine but I only want it to update when the clientId matches what is posted:

```
$database->update("clientInfo", array(
 "businessName" => $_POST['businessName'],
     "contactName" => $_POST['contactName'],
     "businessEmail" => $_POST['businessEmail'],
     "businessPhone" => $_POST['businessPhone'],
     "businessWebsite" => $_POST['businessWebsite'],
     "businessAddress" => $_POST['businessAddress'],
     "businessAddress2" => $_POST['businessAddress2'],
     "businessCity" => $_POST['businessCity'],
     "businessState" => $_POST['businessState'],
     "businessZip" => $_POST['businessZip']
));

//$_POST["clientId"];
```

I am using a newer version of PHP and am a little confused on the syntax, here is how it is with older versions of PHP

http://medoo.in/api/update

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you have `clientId` field in that table, you can try:

```
$database->update("clientInfo", array(
     "businessName" => $_POST['businessName'],
     "contactName" => $_POST['contactName'],
     "businessEmail" => $_POST['businessEmail'],
     "businessPhone" => $_POST['businessPhone'],
     "businessWebsite" => $_POST['businessWebsite'],
     "businessAddress" => $_POST['businessAddress'],
     "businessAddress2" => $_POST['businessAddress2'],
     "businessCity" => $_POST['businessCity'],
     "businessState" => $_POST['businessState'],
     "businessZip" => $_POST['businessZip']
), array(
    "clientId" => $_POST['clientId']
));
```

Hope it helps.